# Database Engine Update Logic

Tags: sql-server, insert-update

When a record is updated in a SQL Server table, how does the db engine physically execute such a request: is it INSERT + DELETE or UPDATE operation?

As we know, the performance of a database and any statements depends on many variables. But I would like to know if some things can be generalized.

- Is there a threshold (table size, query length, # records affected...) after which the database switches to one approach or the other upon UPDATEs?
- If there are times when SQL Server is physically performing insert/delete when a logical update is requested, is there a system view or metric that would show this? - i.e, if there is a running total of all the inserts, updates and deletes that the database engine has performed since it was started, then I would be able to figure out how the database behaves after I issue a single UPDATE.
- Is there any difference between the UPDATE statement's behavior depending on SQL Server version (2008, 2012...)

Many thanks.
Peter

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: You might be able to find more interest in this question on the DBA site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update edits the existing row.  If it was insert/delete, then you'd get update failures for duplicate keys.

Insert/Update/Delete also all can be discretely permissioned.  So a user could update records, but not insert or delete, also leading to that not being the way it works.

Comment: I don't believe you can make this statement -- how the rights are designed has nothing to do with how low level functionality is implemented.

Comment: The transaction log records it as modify row operation as well.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE on base table without triggers is always physical UPDATE. SQL Server has no such threshold. You can look up usage statistics, for example, in sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.